# erro em requisição ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, http

Caros, bom dia!

Estou com um erro que não consigo resolver,
segue log:

```
index.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://meusite.com/testmail.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
jquery.min.js:2 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://meusite.com/testmail.php with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ index.html:302
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
```

já vi sites informando os seguinte:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.website.com");
```

ou até

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [seu website] ou Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

confesso que não entendo muito de rede, não sei onde inserir tais linhas e os artigos que li pareceram grego, como em: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Não consegui aplicar nenhuma solução sugerida.

meu jquery é o seguinte:

```
$("#formcontato").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = new FormData(this); //Creates new FormData object
    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false
    }).done(function(response){ 
      console.log(response);
        $("#server-results").html(response);
        $("#formcontato")[0].reset(); 
    });
});
```

A ação que necessito é feita em partes, pois minha intenção é enviar um email e 
esse email é enviado, porém o javascript não retorna se foi enviado com sucesso e nem mesmo limpa os campos.
Acredito que não a execução não passe do: `.done(function(response){`

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: CORS bloqueia o JS de fazer requisições em servidores que estão em domínios diferentes a menos que este servidor explicitamente permita. O cabeçalho HTTP que você encontrou deve ser configurado no servidor que você está requisitando de forma a permitir que o domínio onde está seu JS faça as requisições.

Comment: Muito obrigado, porém o problema continua